# How to use single sessionFactory for hibernate Intercepter

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, interceptor

I am using Hibernate Interceptor with (hibernate 4.x). I want to perform some operation on save method of Session. So I extend EmptyInterceptor.

It has following methods:

```
onSave() //when save operation is preformed.
postFlush() //called after committed into database
```

PROBLEM: in postFlush() I want to perform SAVE operation. So my control stuck in loop. because whenver session.save() is being called my calls, onSave()  and  postFlush () method of EmptyInterceptor got called to intercept SAVE operation.

TO remove this problem I used TWO session factories. 1 for performing Session operations(save,update etc) and 2nd for HibernateIntercepter.

But I am worried how I can workout this problem with single sessionFactory??

public class AudiLogInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

```
public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state,
        String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    return false;
}

// called after committed into database
public void postFlush(Iterator iterator) {
    // want to perform SAVE operation here with Session.save()
    // But whenever I open new seesion here. It falls in loop
    Session tempSession = HibernateUtil.hibernateTemplateLog
            .getSessionFactory().openSession();

    try {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setName("anyItem");
        item.setValue("anyValue");
        tempSession.save(item);
        tempSession.flush();
    } finally {
        tempSession.close();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not use interceptors to save the objects. You use it to modify/format the items and let the session object do the rest for your but not add new items.

If you really want to add a row at the end of the flush() or commit() then you use Spring-AOP to do that as one option. There you can add Advises to the hibernate services, so, you can save something immediately after running a method.

**Work around** I'd thought is the following.

```
public void postFlush(Iterator iterator) {


for(; iterator.hasNext();) {
   if(!(iterator.next() instanceof Item)){ //<<<<< You verify if you are saving Item or //other objects, if saving Item, skip this block.

   Session tempSession = HibernateUtil.hibernateTemplateLog
            .getSessionFactory().openSession();

    try {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setName("anyItem");
        item.setValue("anyValue");
        tempSession.save(item);
        tempSession.flush();
    } finally {
        tempSession.close();
    }
}
}
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I am using hibernate Interceptor for AUDIT LOGGING. Means whenever there would any SAVE or UPDATE operation then my interceptor will hijeck that method and insert a new record in audit log table( information about the entity. what actually it was before and what is current). Here is reference code.

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/

Comment: In the example link you mentioned, the author was binding the interceptor to a particular session, so, if he does save or update he would not have problem of loop. Are you binding it to a session? or did you apply the interceptor to the whole application? If you applied for a session, then please hav a look at the work around I've mentioned, identify the object that is in the post flush, if it is the AuditLog object, then skip the Audit save block, so, subsequent save will not be called, avoid the program to go into loop.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to bind interceptor to session ?

I am unable to find a method on sessionfactory which takes Connection as argument

Comment: In the example see step No 7. Example: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/. Also, why are you looking for connection argument?

Comment: In step no-7 intercepter object is passing in .openSession() method. But I am using hibernate 4.2.x in which we dont have any openSession() method with argument.

So how should i pass my session reference to my interceptor class ?. (Unless I use static session object and pass through it AuditLogInterceptor class's constructor)

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

AuditLogInterceptor interceptor = new AuditLogInterceptor();
 session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(interceptor);
 interceptor.setSession(session);

Comment: I still couldn't make it happen. The problem still exists.

But I just added workaround and using TWO session factories:
one for my hibernate operations
another for Audit Logging operation (in which I passed interceptor class reference).

BUT i know its not good choice and i really want to use only one session factory and want to bind my interceptor with single session.